# In Android-Studio can we make the default value of translatable="false" as true for string resources?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to translate only a certain set of strings to other languages. I find that the strings editor provided by the Android Studio will be very convenient for managing the strings in over 10+ languages because it provides them column-wise.

Now the problem I am facing is that I want to see only the selected few Strings in this editor which I want to translate. So now I have to add **translatable="false"** to all my existing strings declared in XML anywhere in the whole app. After doing that I will be able to use the "Show Translatable Keys" filter.

I was wondering that if I am able to make the default value of a string resource`s translatable to false, then I will not have to make changes all over the apps. Can that be done?